# How to prevent url redirection if user types it manually to the address bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page there i have a button that fix on it's click what page to redirect with the if else condition but it fixes it as expected but the prob is that when some one manually type the page URL it goes to there also, while i want to prevent this nature what should i do to stop it, please suggest me, i am using asp.net member ship but i suppose that is not much to so it with membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant prevent user from typing in the URL address bar, but on the other hand you can work around this problem by setting a `session` variable to check whether the user came from that button or just typed the page's address and navigate directly to it

```
public void btnNavigate_Click(Object sender,
                           EventArgs e)
{
Session["cameFromBtnClick"] = true;
//Your other code
}
```